# MVC Controller getting 404 error

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller that has several Methods on it.  One to show the View, 6 that are for jquery ajax methods.  The View shows up correctly and here is the simple code

```
 public ActionResult Queues()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

On that view there are 2 datatable.net grids.  That grid gets populated with a ajax call to this

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<JsonResult> QueueOne()
        {
            try
            {
                ....

                var results = await GetData(queryString, authUser.AccessToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTableWrapper<QueueItemForRead>>(results);

                return Json(jsonObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return Json("Error occured please try again");
        }
```

which populates the grid correctly.

I have other functions on the page that call another endpoint on the page

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> ItemComplete(Guid QueueId, long version)
        {
            try
            {
                ...

                var results =
                    await
                        PutData(queryString, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemCompleted), authUser.AccessToken)
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);

                var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewItemCommandResult>(results);

                return Json(jsonObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            }
            return Json("Error occured please try again");
        }
```

and here is the JS that calls the above endpoint

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:18171/Clients/CurrentActivity/ItemComplete' + "?QueueId=" + data + "&version=" + version,
        type: 'PUT',
        //contentType: 'application/json',
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Result === 2) {
                showSuccessNotification(name +
                    " has been Delivered to table.",
                    "Food Delivered");
            }
            //else {

            //}
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //Process error actions
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status + ' ' +
                XMLHttpRequest.statusText);

            $(buttonName).hide();
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            // Code to display spinner
            $(buttonName).hide();
            $(completedAjax).show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            // Code to hide spinner.
            $(completedAjax).hide();
        }
    });
```

but everytime this function is run all I get a 404 error.

Sorry it was bad cut and paste job, the URL actually has signle quotes around it.  and i get the base Url this way

```
 var QueueUrl = '@Url.Action("QueueOne","CurrentActivity")';
```

so when it renders the actual url is '/Clients/CurrentActivity/QueueOne'

Comment: Can you try to add quote to url 'http://localhost:18171/Clients/CurrentActivity/ItemComplete' and add [HttpPut] onto action method ?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the HTTP verb attribute - [HttpPut]

Comment: Your not really hard coding your url like that are you?

Comment: definitly not hard codoing the URL editing the OP to explain more about the url.

Answer (score 0):

your url doesn't contain " " Or ' ' so it isn't considered as string it should be like

```
url: "/Clients/CurrentActivity/ItemComplete?QueueId=" + data + "&version=" + version,
```

Don't Use Your Local Domain IN the Url This Will Cause Problem In production Version if you forget to change it
you can also use Url Helper To Make valid Url Like

```
  url: "@Url.Action("ItemComplete","CurrentActivity",new{area='Clients'})"+"'QueueId=' + data + "&version=" + version,
```